# Two table display in categories

Tags: mysql

I want something like this:

```
Category
item1
Category2
item2
item3
```

But I got

```
Category
item1
Category2
item2
Category2
item3
```

Here is the code

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_cat LEFT JOIN forum ON forum.cat_id = forum_cat.fcat_id ORDER BY forum.cat_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 ?>
```

then some html where I show my data

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you add a little more information?

Comment: Add your whole php thing that's inside while, can't do much with one bracket:P

Comment: "then some html where I show my data" Display that

Comment: i cant add the whole code in here.So here is [link](http://pastebin.com/Ek9vu2iw)

Answer (score 0):

Make a sec array saying if the catagory has already been announced
so above your while loop:

```
$displayed = array();
```

then put this inside your output

```
<?php 
if(!array_key_exists($row['f_cat'], $displayed)) {
echo $row['f_cat'];
$displayed[$row['f_cat']]=1;
} ?>
```